# iPhone and iPad VGA Output

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have heard that officially VGA output is not supported by iOS 3, unless not for developers. It this true?

Will an app using this be approved by Apple?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

External screens are officially supported on iOS 3.2 and above through the [`UIScreen.screens`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIScreen/screens); and `UIWindow` instances can be assigned to particular `UIScreen`. Apple has approved already applications that use it, for example [GoodReader for iPad](http://www.macworld.com/article/152009/2010/06/goodreader_28.html).

Comment: +1:  GoodReader has VGA-out and was approved by Apple, which answers both parts of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Chopper2 app. VGA-output game.